# Strange behaviour in c, fclose(), remove(), rename()

Tags: c, file-io

My programm is meant to be able to either append a line of text to a *.txt file (via `fopen(file,"a")`) or to edit a specific line (via `fopen(file,"w")`)

If i'm starting with editing lines, i can edit as many lines as i want to.
But as soon as i appended a line for the first time, i am not able to edit lines anymore.

The "edit" function (code following) writes all lines from the old file into a new temp-file. Reaching the line i want to edit, it writes the changed line to the temp-file and ends with copying the rest of the lines from the old file. After EOF i close both files, delete the old one and rename the temp-file.

As far as i can tell by debugging my program, the method `editLine()` is writing the temp-file properly. It just won't delete the old file and rename the temp-file. It works quite fine as long as i never appended a line.

Code:

```
void editLine(int line)
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    mystruct a;
    int i = 1;
    fin = fopen(DATAFILE,"r"); //"r" -> read
    fout = fopen(TEMPFILE,"w"); //"w" -> write
    while(mystruct_read(&a, fin)!=EOF)
    {
        if (line==i) getChanges(&a);
        mystruct_write(&a,fout);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    remove(DATAFILE);
    rename(TEMPFILE, DATAFILE);
    return;
}

void appendLine()
{
    FILE *file;
    mystruct a = {0};
    file = fopen(DATAFILE,"a");
    getChanges(&a);
    mystruct_write(&a,file);
    fclose(file);
    return;
}
```

Can anybody tell me why the program behaves like that? And what do i have to change? Thx ...

Comment: Kindly check for the success of `fopen()` before using the returned pointer.

Comment: Do you have the `DATAFILE` open somewhere else? Check the return values of `remove` and `rename` and if they fail (they return `-1`) then check `errno` for what's wrong.

Comment: i haven't checked the return values so far ... gonna do that now tho. But as said, the read and write operations are working properly as expected. It's just the `remove()` and `rename()` functions that aren't working anymore.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how do i check `errno`? Pretty new to C programming :/

Comment: If e.g. `remove` fails, it will return `-1`, first check for that. If it fails you can print the error in two ways: Using either [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) or using [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror). Both links contains examples on how to use the functions. Important note: Don't use [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) (either directly or indirectly through e,g. `perror`) unless the previous function actually failed, the value of `errno` is undefined unless a function actually fails.

Comment: Checking the return values from rename() and remove() may provide a clue.

Comment: please  use     perror for checking what fails with remove

Comment: if  `editLine` is called by *either* `getChanges` or `mystruct_write`, then you have a file pointer open already on that file. Why you're not checking the success/failure of your file api calls is beyond me. Seeing **all** the relevant code in a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: In C, loops like `while(something != EOF) { ... }` are almost always an error since in C EOF is detected not until the I/O was performed (while most newbies expect an empty file to yield true for `feof(file)` before anything is read).

Comment: @WhozCraig `editLine()` isn't called by any of these methods. I tested the return values now: `remove()` and `rename()` both returning `-1` ... `perror` on `remove()` is telling me `Permission denied`. I will recheck if i left the file open somewhere else ...

Comment: Sry for the trouble i made there ... i was sure i had the file closed :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was a an `fopen()` call on the file after the `appendLine()` call.
I guess i somehow inserted it there accidentally.

So the answer is:
Because the file was still opened it couldn't be removed or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestion:

1) try to add delay between `fclose()` and `remove()`, perhaps OS blocks the file for a while after closing.

2) try to use `fflush()` before closing file.